# Where can I find the Fluent API documentation for Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I've searched with no luck. I find lots of articles, but no docs on MSDN for the Fluent API in Entity Framework 4.1.

Microsoft cannot have released thsi without documentation, so it must be my searches that is off target. Anyone care to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are looking for this page. :)

[MSDN Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295844%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)